# After performing sqoop import from rdbms , how to check whether the data is properly imported or not in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

Is there any tools available? 
Normally I check by doing manual checks like count(*), min , max , doing select where query in both rdbms and hive table. Is there any other way?

Comment: Sqoop eval tool can be used for executing count(*) on database, also sqoop validation: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#validation

Comment: Thank you for the answer @leftjoin.If we want to do column level checking between src -rdbms and that-hive, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `--validate` in sqoop import or export to get row count between  source and destination.

**Update:** Column Level checking.
There is no in built parameter in `sqoop` to achieve this.But you can do this as below:

1.Store the data imported in a temp table.

**Use shell script for below:**

2.Get the data from source table and compare it with temp table using shell variables.

3.If it matches,then copy the data from temp to original table

Comment: thank you Subash. Before loading into hadoop can we do any column level checking . How it works.

Comment: Hi @Shilpa ,Updated my answer as per your comment.And if the solution provided is satisfactory as per your actual query,kindly upvote.